# How to Change Bibliography numbering style in thesis format

Tags: bibliographies, thesis

I am using this thesis template. I need help to change the bibliography number format.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% preample %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%% packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % euro quality fonts [T1] (togeth. w/ textcomp)
\usepackage{textcomp, amssymb}  % additional symbols (there are more packages)
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % umlaute in input file
\usepackage{setspace}           % doublespacing
\usepackage{anysize}            % margin package sets tighter margins
\usepackage[all]{xy}            % creating figures within latex
\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}% subfigures: figures within figures

%\marginsize{1.2in}{0.9in}{1.1in}{0.9in} % small margins
\marginsize{1.2in}{0.9in}{0.5in}{1.5in} % small margins

\usepackage{ifpdf}              % if pdflatex then ... else ...
\ifpdf
  \pdfadjustspacing=1           % make pdflatex behave like latex
  \usepackage{aeguill}          % PS converted CM fonts for better acro preview
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % graphics packages
  \usepackage[pdftex]{color}    % color packages
  \usepackage[pdftex]{thumbpdf} % create thumbnails (run thumbpdf as well)
  \usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,%
              pagebackref=true, % bibliography -> text
              linktocpage=true, % toc etc: make page number active (not name)
              plainpages=false, % distinguish roman and arabic pagenumbers
              bookmarksopen=true,%
              bookmarksnumbered=true,%
              pdfauthor={Stefan Schäckeler},%
              pdftitle={Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet},%
              pdfsubject={PhD Thesis},%
              pdfkeywords={Embedded Systems, Code Compaction},%
             ]{hyperref}        % clickabe references
\else
  \usepackage[hypertex,
              plainpages=false, % distinguish roman and arabic pagenumbers
              linktocpage=true, % toc etc: make page number active (not name)
             ]{hyperref}        % clickabe references in .dvi
                                % purposely included before color package
  \usepackage[dvips]{color}     % color packages; needed by xy
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}  % graphics packages
\fi


% hyperref must be the second last package and glossary the last package

% index
\usepackage{makeidx}                       % for \printindex
\makeindex                                 % creates paper.idx index file

% glossary
\usepackage[style=super, cols=3]{glossary} % for \printclossary
\makeglossary                              % creates paper.glo glossary file


%%% style and finetuning %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{plain}               % pagestyle: headings, empty, plain

% new theorems
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}


%%% document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} % titlepage does not get a number - that's odd, but good.

\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Title}{label:title}\fi              \input{titlepage.tex}

\newpage                                                     \input{spruch.tex}

{\doublespacing
\newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Acknowledgement}{label:ack}\fi\input{acknowledge.tex}
\newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Abstract}{label:abst}\fi     \input{abstract.tex}
}

\newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Table of Contents}{label:toc}\fi \tableofcontents
\newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Figures}{label:lof}\fi     \listoffigures
\newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Tables}{label:lot}\fi       \listoftables

{\doublespacing
\newpage\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage\input{body.tex}

%\input{references.bib}
% Bibliography and Glossary          (\phantomsection is needed for hyperlinks)

\newpage\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}              % add Bibliography to TOC
\bibliographystyle{alpha}\bibliography{references}


\newpage\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}                   % add Index to TOC
\printindex

\newpage\phantomsection%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}                  % add Glossary to TOC
\printglossary

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image: Out Put]

The original output is as follows but I need the above format.

[image]

Comment: Change `pagebackref=true,` to `pagebackref=false,`. If you are not forced to use this template, you may want to consider *not* using it and starting from a more minimal setup and building up from there. (Most editors nowadays save files in UTF8 and modern LaTeX also assumes this as the default encoding, so setting `latin1` explicitly suggests an older setup.)

Comment: moewe: Thank you for your valuable commend. How to change the numbering format. I need to change the format  [ASU86] into [1]. Thank you.

Comment: Replace `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` with a numeric style, e.g. `\bibliographystyle{plain}` or `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` (`plain` if you want your entries sorted by author, `unsrt` if you want them sorted by citation order). But there are many, many more styles available.

Comment: moewe: Thank you so much.